# Looping Increment Not Working

Tags: c++, loops, iteration

I am a beginner to programming and am new to the forum. I have been working on a beginning project, a game of Hangman. I am using an iteration constant, numberGuesses to track how many guesses the user has inputted. However, my program is not iterating properly and I cannot figure why for whatever reason. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string userWord = " ";
    char userLetter = ' ';
    int numberGuesses = 0;
    string board1 =
        " -------|\n"
        " |      |\n"
        "        |\n"
        "        |\n"
        "        |\n"
        "        |\n"
        "      -----";
    string board2 = 
        " -------|\n"
        " |      |\n"
        " O      |\n"
        "        |\n"
        "        |\n"
        "        |\n"
        "      -----";
    string board3 = 
        " -------|\n"
        " |      |\n"
        " O      |\n"
        " |      |\n"
        "        |\n"
        "        |\n"
        "      -----";
    string board4 = 
        " -------|\n"
        " |      |\n"
        " O      |\n"
        "-|      |\n"
        "        |\n"
        "        |\n"
        "      -----";
    string board5 = 
        " -------|\n"
        " |      |\n"
        " O      |\n"
        "-|-     |\n"
        "        |\n"
        "        |\n"
        "      -----";
    string board6 = 
        " -------|\n"
        " |      |\n"
        " O      |\n"
        "-|-     |\n"
        "/       |\n"
        "        |\n"
        "      -----";
    string board7 = 
        " -------|\n"
        " |      |\n"
        " O      |\n"
        "-|-     |\n"
        "/ \\     |\n"
        "        |\n"
        "      -----";

    cout << "Enter a word to guess: ";
    cin >> userWord;
    for (int i = 0; i < userWord.length(); i++)
       {
           userWord[i] = toupper(userWord[i]);
       }
    cout << "You entered: " << userWord << endl;



    do 
    {

        if (numberGuesses = 0)
        {
            cout << board1;
        }    
        if (numberGuesses = 1)
        {
            cout << board2;
        }
        else if (numberGuesses = 2)
        {
            cout << board3;   
        }
        else if (numberGuesses = 3)
        {
            cout << board4;
        }
        else if (numberGuesses = 4)
        {
            cout << board5;
        }
        else if (numberGuesses = 5)
        {
            cout << board6;
        }
        else if (numberGuesses = 6)
        {
            cout << board7;
        }

        cout << "\nEnter a letter to guess: ";
        cin >> userLetter;
        userLetter = toupper(userLetter);
        cout << "You entered: " << userLetter << endl;

        if (userWord.find(userLetter) != string::npos)
            cout << userLetter << " is in the word to guess." << endl;
        else
            cout << userLetter << " is NOT in the word to guess." << endl;

        numberGuesses++;

    }

    while (numberGuesses <= 6);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You could eliminate a lot of `if` statements by using an array of `board`s (or string).  Something like `cout << board_array[numberGuesses] << endl;`

Answer (score 10):

`=` is the assignment operator. To check for equality, you should use the `==` operator:

```
if (numberGuesses == 0) {
    // Here -------^
    // (and do the same for the other conditions)
```